# Rewrite JavaScript IIFE with falafel?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, jquery-mobile, browserify

I'm trying to use a JavaScript library (jQuery mobile) in my project that wraps itself in a few IIFE's in different formats such as:

```
(function ( root, doc, factory ) {
    if ( typeof define === "function" && define.amd ) {
        // AMD. Register as an anonymous module.
        define( [ "jquery" ], function ( $ ) {
            factory( $, root, doc );
            return $.mobile;
        });
    } else {
        // Browser globals
        factory( root.jQuery, root, doc );
    }
}( this, document, function ( jQuery, window, document, undefined ) {
(function( $ ) {
    $.mobile = {};
}( jQuery ));
```

and also...

```
(function( $, window, undefined ) {
// more code
)( jQuery, this );
```

I'm bundling my project with browserify and the problem is that `this` is undefined because it gets wrapped in another wrapper function by my bundler. There are issues on github for CommonJS support with jQuery mobile but they refuse to write additional support for it.

I stumbled onto falafel recently and now I'm wondering if there is a way to rewrite the above closures respectively to this:

```
function(root, doc, factor){
   // main closure
}(this || window, document, function(){})

function($, window, undefined) {
  // more code
}(jQuery, this || window)
```

Comment: I don't really understand what you're asking for here, but you can pass `this` into an IIFE by using `.call(this)` at the end of the IIFE.  `(function() {}).call(this)`

Comment: Can falafel be used to write that in for me?